# Find key if text matches value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to highlight only the number between the brackets in regular js. Colors are based on value (type of fruit in this scenario).
HTML

```html
<a class="temple" href="something @ URL">LARGE FRUIT (215)</a>
<a class="temple" href="something @ URL">PINEAPPLE (38)</a>
<a class="temple" href="something @ URL">RED APPLE (76)</a>
```

My Dict

```
var my_dict = {'BLUE':['ORANGE'], ['GRAPE']
               'YELLOW':['PINEAPPLE'], ['KIWI']}
```

I could do them independently using but it's messy and may break the code if a tag is removed:

```
let Pineapple       = document.querySelector('.temple')
PINEAPPLE.innerHTML = PINEAPPLE.innerHTML.replace(/\([^\)]*\)/, '<span class="red">$&</span>')
```

This is what I have so far:

```
function color(){
  let fruits = document.querySelector('.temple')
  for (let i = 0; i<fruits.length; i++) {
    let str = fruits.innerHTML //this gives me the text I need.
```

My goal is to use the results (value) to find the key and ultimately color just the number.

Comment: `querySelector` returns null or one element, so your for loop will only execute at most once. You probably want `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Your json/dictionary needs to be corrected. Your looping will vary based on how your JSON/dictionary is actually setup,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that ?

```js
const my_dict = 
  { BLUE:   [ 'ORANGE', 'GRAPE' ] 
  , YELLOW: [ 'PINEAPPLE', 'KIWI' ]  
  , RED:    [ 'APPLE' ]  
  };

// ES5 code
const my_dict_reverse = 
  Object
    .keys( my_dict)
    .reduce( function(r,k)
      {
      my_dict[k].forEach( function(fruit) { r[fruit] = k } );
      return r;
      },{});
// my_dict_reverse = { ORANGE: 'BLUE', GRAPE: 'BLUE', PINEAPPLE: 'YELLOW', KIWI: 'YELLOW', APPLE: 'RED' }
  
document
  .querySelectorAll('.temple')
  .forEach( function(el)
  {
  let pos        = el.textContent.search(/\([^\)]*\)/)
    , fruit      = el.textContent.slice(0,pos)
    , val        = el.textContent.slice(pos) 
    , colorClass = my_dict_reverse[ fruit.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')] || ''
    ;
  el.innerHTML = fruit
               + '<span class="'  + colorClass + '">'
               + val +'</span>';
  });


/* ES10 code ...

const my_dict_reverse = Object.keys( my_dict).reduce((r,k)=>
  {
  my_dict[k].forEach(fruit=>r[fruit]=k)
  return r
  },{})
  
document.querySelectorAll('.temple').forEach(el=>
  {
  let [fruit, val] = el.textContent.split(/(?=\()|(?<=\))/)
    , colorClass   = my_dict_reverse[ fruit.trim()] ?? ''
    ;
  el.innerHTML = `${fruit}<span class="${colorClass}">${val}</span>`
  })
*/
```

```css
body { background: steelblue; }
a.temple     {
  color           : black; 
  float           : left;
  clear           : both;
  text-decoration : none;
  }
span.RED     { color : red;    }
span.BLUE    { color : blue;   }
span.YELLOW  { color : yellow; }
```

```html
<a class="temple" href="something @ URL">LARGE FRUIT (215)</a>
<a class="temple" href="something @ URL">PINEAPPLE (38)</a>
<a class="temple" href="something @ URL">APPLE (76)</a>
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain correctly. I edited me dict to better show what I meant.  The color of the bracket should correspond to the key color.  In the example, Pineapple / Kiwi should be 'yellow' and 'Orange' / 'Grape' should be blue.

Comment: Thank you.  The browser I'm using doesn't accept look-behinds for javascript.  So I put the old regex code in.  Then it didn't like the '??' (unexpected token for the second question mark) so I changed it to '||'.  I read that they're slightly different but can be interchangeable. My output changed everything to "${fruit}${val}".  Not sure what is going on

Comment: ok. your code uses a lookbehind(<=) in your regex here "(/(?=\()|(?<=\))/)".  My browser does not accept those so I used "(/\([^\)]*\)/)".  Then I was getting an UNEXPECTED TOKEN error for the second question mark here: "trim()] ?? ".  I'm not sure why. So I substituted the question marks with "trim()] ||".

Comment: oh ok. yeah so instead of just changing the color within the parenthesis. It replaced everything. The only thing displaying is ${fruit}${val} for each entry.  Just saw you provided updates. Going ot work through that now.

Comment: no. I am getting "ARROW FUNCTION SHOULD NOT RETURN ASSIGNMENT'. After some research, I tried adding brackets to "forEach(fruit=>r[fruit]=k)".  Changed to forEach(fruit=>{r[fruit]=k}). Still getting ${fruit}${val} so far

Comment: I'm in the debugger.  Everything is working right until this line: el.innerHTML = '${fruit}<span class="${colorClass}">${val}</span>'.  That's when it changes to ${fruit}${val}

Comment: OK, @ryda, try my last last last update... And don't forget to let me know how it is then...

Comment: Is there another way to build a span class?
span.RED     { color : red;    }
span.BLUE    { color : blue;   }
span.YELLOW  { color : yellow; }

Comment: Everything else is working 
Tried  if (colorClass ==RED){ 
            span.color.style = 'red'
                 }
but 'span' is undefined

Comment: @ryda yes you can do that, but it is easier to write your `css` rules rather than adding your `if`s in the javascript part

Comment: thank you! I used the CSS class for tampermonkey to get it working (GM_addStyle)